# Background disappears when expanding an element CSS?

Tags: css

When I add a new element in (using JavaScript event listener to set display from none to grid) the background of the body behind and around the element (which is set to 80% width) goes solid white. If I remove html tag from the following code it fixes it but then the body background image doesn't fill the entire screen on mobile. Really stuck on a fix if anyone can help?

photo below after the code

Thank you

body css

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    background: url(/resources/clearday.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

element css

```
.extraForecast {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 4fr) 1fr;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2.15rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhnaG.jpg)

Comment: Try changing the ```height``` and ```width``` properties of the ```body, html``` to ```height: 100vh``` and ```width: 100vw```

Comment: i have tried this and the result is the same.

Comment: https://danielwilstrop.github.io/. if anyone would like to see the issue in play i have added the site to GH pages here

Comment: Could you update you question wih yout html code?

Comment: Remove your ```height``` tag from the body

Comment: Is there a reason for painting a background image on both body and html?

Comment: just trying workaounds. if i removed the html tag it worked on desktop but went crazy on mobiles. its been answered below and works a treat. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only tested quickly on mobile, but stopping the background image from scrolling with the page seemed to fix it.

To do this I added

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

to the CSS for `body, html`